# How to label categorical variables in Pandas in order?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe with the following categorical variables as columns on the left, and their specific realizations on the right,

[image]

(apologies for low-res).

For a statistical regression, I want to label all of these categorical variables, so, for example, in `LotShape`, `Reg` becomes `0`, `IR1` becomes `1`, `IR2` `2`, and `IR3` `3`. I found that scikit-learn's `LabelEncoder` can do the [job](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), but there's a problem. Some of these categorical variables are implicitly ordinal, and `0`, `1`, ... need to be assigned to the right labels, and `LotShape` only happens to be in order there.

So my question is, how would I efficiently, in some order that I specify, label a large number of categorical variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help.

```
x= ['GA','TA','SA','TA','GA','TA','SA']

import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing.label import _encode
from sklearn.utils import column_or_1d
x = column_or_1d(x, warn=True)
classes_,encoded_values = _encode(x,uniques=np.array(['GA','TA','SA']),encode=True)
encoded_values, classes_

#(array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]), ['GA', 'TA', 'SA'])

#comparing with labelencoder, which will sort the labels before encoding
le = LabelEncoder()

le.fit_transform(x),le.classes_

#
(array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1], dtype=int64),
 array(['GA', 'SA', 'TA'], dtype='<U2'))
```

Comment: This ended up being the mundane answer that worked. The implicit solution I see here is to manually specify the order of the variables to be transformed within `LabelEncoder`.

Answer (score 3):

One can use base python function `list.index()` for this.

Taking example lists from Coolio2654's answer:

```
x= ['GA','TA','SA','TA','GA','TA','SA']
orderlist = ['GA','TA','SA']
```

Using `map` function:

```
list(map(lambda a: orderlist.index(a), x))
```

Or list comprehension:

```
[orderlist.index(a) for a in x]
```

Output for each of above is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Above can be put in a function which can be called for each categorical column.